# How to express membership in multiple categories in R?

Tags: r

How does one express a linear model where observations can belong to multiple categories and the number of categories is large?

For example, using time dummies as the categories, here is a problem that is easy to set up since the number of categories (time periods) is small and known:

```
tmp <- "day 1, day 2
0,1
1,0
1,1"
periods <- read.csv(text = tmp)
y <- rnorm(3)
print(lm(y ~ day.1 + day.2 + 0, data=periods))
```

Now suppose that instead of two days there were 100. Would I need to create a formula like the following?

```
y ~ day.1 + day.2 + ... + day.100 + 0
```

Presumably such a formula would have to be created programmatically.  This seems inelegant and un-R-like.

What is the right R way to tackle this?  For example, aside from the formula problem, is there a better way to create the dummies than creating a matrix of 1s and 0s (as I did above)?  For the sake of concreteness, say that the actual data consists (for each observation) of a start and end date (so that `tmp` would contain a 1 in each column between start and end).

---

### Update:

Based on the answer of @jlhoward, here is a larger example:

```
num.observations <- 1000
# Manually create 100 columns of dummies called x1, ..., x100
periods <- data.frame(1*matrix(runif(num.observations*100) > 0.5, nrow = num.observations))
y <- rnorm(num.observations)
print(summary(lm(y ~ ., data = periods)))
```

It illustrates the manual creation of a data frame of dummies (1s and 0s).  I would be interested in learning whether there is a more R-like way of dealing with these "multiple dummies per observation" issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.` notation to include all variables other than the response in a formula, and `-1` to remove the intercept. Also, put everything in your data frame; don't make `y` a separate vector.

```
set.seed(1)    # for reproducibility
df  <- data.frame(y=rnorm(3),read.csv(text=tmp))
fit.1 <- lm(y ~ day.1 + day.2 + 0, df)
fit.2 <- lm(y ~ -1 + ., df)
identical(coef(fit.1),coef(fit.2))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: This is a great answer -- thank you.  Is there a better way of dealing with dummies than to manually populate a data frame with 1s and 0s (`df[2:3]` in the snippet above)?  What I have in mind is something like the possibility of adding a `factor` to a formula.

Comment: I'd need to see your actual data. The problem, I think, is that some of your cases (row 3 in the example) have more than one factor level.

Comment: Exactly! What is difficult about this (for me) was dealing with the fact that some observations can be assigned to _multiple_ time dummies.  So the general case that I'm interested in has each row assigned to (say) dozens of time periods.  If it would help, I could create a MWE that is large (as opposed to the tiny example I gave above).

Comment: Or upload the data somewhere and post a link.